# Can Postgresql access ARRAY slice with step size ie. return a downsampled array?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, slice

I've searched all over and read through the Postgresql array docs. Perhaps this is supported in postgres. I can get a down-sampled version of a numpy array like this:

> > numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])[0:9:2] # the 2 here is the step size for the slice
> > out: array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])

Can one do something similar for a postgresql array?

> > SELECT (ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])[1:10:2]; // Don't forget 1 based indexing!

The above doesn't work. I'd expect this operation could be very fast in an array with elements of a fixed size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, postgres does not support syntax like you would find in python for skipping elements of an array.  You would have to unnest it, to split it into rows, and then aggregate it again.  Using WITH ORDINALITY in conjunction with unnest allows you to get the index of each element of the array.

```
SELECT array_agg(x order by n) 
FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) with ordinality as o(x, n) 
WHERE (n-1) % 2 = 0;
  array_agg
-------------
 {1,3,5,7,9}
```

You could use (n-1) % 3 for every third element, etc.

You could even create a simple function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_step(p_array anyarray, p_step int) 
RETURNS anyarray AS $$
    SELECT array_agg(x order by n) FROM unnest(p_array) WITH ORDINALITY AS o(x, n) WHERE (n-1) % p_step = 0;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
PARALLEL SAFE;

select array_step(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 3);
 array_step
------------
 {1,4,7,10}

select array_step((ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])[2:8], 3);
 array_step
------------
 {2,5,8}
```

Comment: Thanks- very nice solution. This seems like it could work well although a little less convenient than I was hoping. I'll give it a try. It seems like it might have to check every value of the ordinality rather than just skip a known step size to obtain a downsampled like I was hoping but maybe it has some 'under the hood' optimization that I don't anticipate. I clearly am no expert about how postgres works.